# vb.net select specific lines, from one line to another line

Tags: vb.net, line

I want write this code but it doesn't work for me

```
    Dim x

    Dim y

    x = TextBox1.Lines(1 - 5)


    y = TextBox1.Lines(6 - 10)


    TextBox2.Text = x
    TextBox3.Text = y
```

I want to take value from textbox.. x from line 1 to line 5
, y from line 6 to line 10

Comment: When you say it doesn't work for you, what do you mean? What is the result you are seeing?

Comment: Could you explain your problem more?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in WindowsApplication4.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information. Don't add further information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there are 10 lines in there, otherwise add some validation / error handling

```
Dim x = TextBox1.Lines.Take(5)
Dim y = TextBox1.Lines.Skip(5).Take(5)
TextBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, x)
TextBox3.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, y)
```

You don't even need x and y according to your edit. Simply this

```
TextBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, TextBox1.Lines.Take(5))
TextBox3.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, TextBox1.Lines.Skip(5).Take(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must specify a type in the `Dim` statement. I assume that you want a `String` where you can store these lines.

Then `1 - 5` and `6 - 10` simply calculate `1 minus 5` and `6 minus 10` and do not specify line ranges. You can use LINQ to select the desired lines. But then you must join these lines given as string enumeration to build a single string.

```
Dim x, y As String

x = String.Join(vbNewLine, TextBox1.Lines.Take(5)) 'Lines 1 - 5
y = String.Join(vbNewLine, TextBox1.Lines.Skip(5).Take(5)) 'Lines 6 - 10
```

Also note that the `Lines` property returns an array of strings. Array indexes are 0-based in VB.NET! I.e., the first line is `TextBox1.Lines(0)`.